# Java, verification ResponseCode URL

Tags: java, url

This is code:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception 
{

    URL url = new URI("http://www.google.com").toURL();
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    Reader rd = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

    EditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
    HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument) kit.createDefaultDocument();
    kit.read(rd, doc, 0);

    HTMLDocument.Iterator it = doc.getIterator(HTML.Tag.A);
    while (it.isValid()) {
    SimpleAttributeSet s = (SimpleAttributeSet) it.getAttributes();

    String link = (String) s.getAttribute(HTML.Attribute.HREF);
    if (link != null) {
    System.out.println(link);
   }
   it.next();
}
```

}
}

Question:

How to do that ......with every page contained in google.com check getResponseCode?

example:

http://www.google.pl/intl/pl/services/ -ResponseCode 200

https://plus.google.com/102407376649446415369 -ResponseCode 407

........

.........
This small program will generate a google.com pages. How do I make each page was generated Displayed with ResponseCode answer? I would like to check the notes separately on each side, only one code to check all of them.
I can use  loop?

Answer (score 0):

Just call, err, would you believe `URLConnnection.getResponseCode(),` before you get the input stream.

Comment: I don't understand a word of that. Try again.

Comment: This small program will generate a google.com pages. How do I make each generated page was displayed with ResponseCode answer?

I would like to not check the separately on each side, only to check one code all of them.